# Why doesn't the result from sys.stdin.readline() compare equal when I expect it to?

Tags: python

I m trying to compare keyboard input to a string:

```
import sys

# read from keyboard
line = sys.stdin.readline()
if line == "stop":
    print 'stop detected'
else:
    print 'no stop detected'
```

When I type 'stop' at the keyboard and enter, I want the program to print 'stop detected' but it always prints 'no stop detected'. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `if line.strip() == "stop"`

Comment: The real lessons to take away from this are: (a) string comparisons are literal and precise ... they are sensitive to whitespace, punctuation, capitalization, and even non-printable, possibly "hidden" characters; and (b) methods like deadline() may have subtleties in their return values.  For example there *might* be a \n (newline) at the end of an input line ... but it's possible that the input stream can return a string at EOF without a trailing newline.  (So don't assume that every string returned by readline() will necessarily end with \n).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys.stdin.readline()` includes the trailing newline character.  Either use `raw_input()`, or compare `line.rstrip("\n")` to the string you are looking for (or even `line.strip().lower()`).